# Need to combine multiple rows in MySql or Access with one row

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table that has a sku number, attribute_name and a attribute value. Each sku could have many attritbutes with it.

Right now the table looks like this.

```
SKU,             ATT_NM,                                          ATT_VAL
TOST3580,   Supply Type,                                    Toner
TOST3580,   Pre-Consumer Recycled Content Percent [Nom],    0 %
TOST3580,   Post-Consumer Recycled Content Percent [Nom],   0 %
TOST3580,   Total Recycled Content Percent [Nom],           0 %
TOST3580,   OEM/Compatible,                                 OEM
```

I need them to be more like this.

```
SKU,ATT_NM,ATT_VAL,ATT_NM1,ATT_VAL1
TOST3580,Supply,Type,Toner,Pre-Consumer Recycled Content Percent,0 %
```

adding each attribute value. so for instance the example above would have 5 different attributes. Each SKU has anywhere from 2-20 attributes. Any help would be awesome. Sorry for the bad formatting.

This can be done in either Access or MySQL

Comment: 1) I don't quite get the result. You've lost data. EG: Where has `OEM/Compatible` gone to? 2) Did you mean that you wanted to add for each `sku` all `att_nm` concatenated?

Comment: You should probably move the ATT_NM text content to another table and then link to it with ATT_ID in this table.

Comment: Yes for each SKU, I want to add all the ATT_NM and ATT_VAL together on one row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (with MySQL) -

```
SELECT
    SKU,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ATT_NM = 'Supply Type', ATT_VAL, NULL)) AS `Supply Type`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ATT_NM = 'Pre-Consumer Recycled Content Percent [Nom]', ATT_VAL, NULL)) AS `Pre-Consumer Recycled Content Percent [Nom]`,
    ...
FROM table
GROUP BY SKU
```

You could retrieve the list of attribs using -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ATT_NM
FROM table
```

and then use the values returned to build the prev query.